# How to bring stock info out of the dropdown and display as a text in Magento configurable product page?

Tags: magento-1.7

I opened template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml and found:

```
<select name="super_attribute[<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]" id="attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>" class="required-entry super-attribute-select">
                    <option><?php echo $this->__('Choose an Option...') ?></option>
                  </select>
```

I thought I'll find from there the code to get that info but there's just one option "Choose an Option..."

Comment: I mean customers open the product (not me) in front end and if they want to buy the item they have to pick the color from dropdown. In dropdown options they see color name + how many items in stock. I would like to have the info, how many products are in the stock for each color not only in dropdown but also somewhere else in product page.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the configuration of the attribute that you select. If COLOR is the attribute, then it will in the field of "Catalog Input Type for Store Owner". Here you have to select "TextField" instead of dropdown. See the below [image]image.

Once attribute is created, it is not possible to edit that field. You have to delete that attribute and again re-create it.

**EDIT:**

Is this what you want?

[image]

Comment: Oh, sorry - I mean customers open the product (not me) in front end and if they want to buy the item they have to pick the color from dropdown. In dropdown options they see color name + how many items in stock. I would like to have the info, how many products are in the stock for each color not only in dropdown but also somewhere else in product page.

Comment: can u add screenshot of the dropdown values that you can see in frontend??

Comment: Yep, that's it. http://screencast.com/t/1VKvtECrWw - you see that green has delivery time 6 days but in stock is one white tent etc. But you have to open the dropdown menu to see it. I want it to be just a normal text somewhere upper and better location in product page. Thanks a lot:)